# CSS - Menubar changes width while hover

Tags: css

I created a menu and a submenu that should appear after I hover over the list elements of the main menu. The problem is that the widths of the main menu's list elements changes while hovering, and it looks puzzling. I tried it with a fixed width, but the space between the menu items is too big then.

I also tried to set the submenu to position absolute, but the problem was that the submenu was always located at the same position and not beneath the main menu's item which was active.

[I created a codepen for this issue](http://codepen.io/seraphzz/pen/fvmpd)).

HTML:

```
<ul class="menubar">
  <li class="menubar-li"><a href="#">Unternehmen</a>
    <ul class="menubar-sub">
      <li class="menubar-sub-li"><a href="../html/profil.html">Profil</a>
      <li class="menubar-sub-li"><a href="../html/meilensteine.html">Meilensteine</a>
      <li class="menubar-sub-li"><a href="../html/team.html">Team</a>
      <li class="menubar-sub-li"><a href="../html/news.html">News</a>
      <li class="menubar-sub-li"><a href="../html/jobs.html">Jobs</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="menubar-li"><a href="#">Kompetenzen</a>
    <ul class="menubar-sub">
  <li class="menubar-sub-li"><a href="../html/kreation.html">Kreation</a>
    <ul class="menubar-subsub">
      <li><a href="../html/strategie.html">Strategie</a>
      <li><a href="../html/design.html">Design</a>
      <li><a href="../html/online.html">Online</a>
      <li><a href="../html/reinzeichnung.html">Reinzeichnung</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="menubar-sub-li"> <a href="../html/prepress.html">Prepress</a>
    <ul  class="menubar-subsub">
     <li><a href="../html/seitenproduktion.html">Seitenproduktion</a></li>
     <li><a href="../html/kreativretusche.html">Kreativretusche</a>
     <li><a href="../html/colormanagement.html">Colormanagement</a>
     <li><a href="../html/proofen.html">Proofen</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menubar-sub-li"><a href="../html/druck.html">Druck</a>
    <ul  class="menubar-subsub">
      <li><a href="../html/personalisiert.html">Personalisiert</a></li>
      <li><a href="../html/web2print.html">Web 2 Print</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="menubar-sub-li"><a href="../html/katalogmanagement.html">Katalogmanagement</a></ul>
  </li>

  <li class="menubar-li"><a href="../html/portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li class="menubar-li"><a href="#">Service</a>
      <ul class="menubar-sub">
        <li class="menubar-sub-li"><a href="../html/mediapool.html">Mediapool</a></li>
        <li class="menubar-sub-li"><a href="../html/duon.html">DUON</a></li>
        <li class="menubar-sub-li"><a href="../html/datenupload.html">Datenupload</a></li>
        <li class="menubar-sub-li"><a href="../html/downloads.html">Downloads</a>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menubar-li"><a href="#">Kontakt</a>
     <ul class="menubar-sub">
       <li class="menubar-sub-li"><a href="../html/ansprechpartner.html">Ansprechpartner</a></li>
       <li class="menubar-sub-li"><a href="../html/anfahrt.html">Anfahrt</a></li>
       <li class="menubar-sub-li"><a href="../html/impressum.html">Impressum</a></li>
     </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.menubar {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 16px;
}

.menubar a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 13px;
    position: relative;
}

.menubar-li {
    float: left;
    height:29px;
    line-height:29px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.menubar-li:hover {
    background-color: #94ba1d;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.menubar-li:hover .menubar-sub {
    display: block;
}

.menubar-sub {
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    background-color: #94ba1d;
    position: relative;
    left: -10px;
}

.menubar-sub-li {
    line-height: 14px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.menubar-subsub {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: This question should be closed as too localized. And you should simply profile and debug your codes. There is no magic involved here, just trial, error, and reading CSS documentation and tutorials. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can position the submenu below the main menu button by setting the main menu button to `position: relative` and placing the (absolute) submenu inside it. You then show/hide the submenu by toggling `overflow: hidden` and `visible`.

Here is a demo: http://codepen.io/seraphzz/pen/osGnh